# Is there any theorem connect to this problem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

It is a question I always ask when I was a primary student:

Could a number only contains digit'1' with $p$ digits writes
$$A=\frac{10^{p}-1}{9} = \underbrace{11\cdots 1}_{p\text{ digits}}$$
be a prime?

When $p$ is not a prime, the factorization of $A$ is obvious, but if $p$ is a prime, the factorization of $A$ may be subtle.

Here I made a list of some result for prime $p$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
p & \ \text{factors} \\
\hline
3 & 3 \times 37\\
5 & 41 \times 271 \\
7 & 239 \times 4649 \\
11 & 21649 \times 513239 \\
13 & 53 \times 79 \times 265371653 \\
17 & 2071723 \times 5363222357 \\
19 & \text{prime} \\
23 & \text{prime} \\
29 & 3191 \times 16763 \times 43037 \times 62003 \times 77843839397 \\
31 & 2791 \times 6943319 \times 57336415063790604359 \\
37 & 2028119 \times 247629013 \times 2212394296770203368013 \\
41 & 83 \times 1231 \times 538987 \times 201763709900322803748657942361 \\
43 & 173 \times 1527791 \times 1963506722254397 \times 2140992015395526641 \\
47 & 35121409 \times 316362908763458525001406154038726382279 \\
53 & 107 \times 1659431 \times 1325815267337711173 \times 47198858799491425660200071 \\
59 & 2559647034361 \times 4340876285657460212144534289928559826755746751 \\
61 & 733 \times 4637 \times 329401 \times 974293 \times 1360682471 \times 106007173861643 \times 7061709990156159479 \\
67 & 493121 \times 79863595778924342083 \times 28213380943176667001263153660999177245677 \\
\end{array}
$$

I am not major in number theory, just curious again if there is any theorem or former work on this kind of question.

Comment: You can start at http://oeis.org/A004023

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek this is helpful! I just guess there must be a sequence on OEIS, but nowhere to start.

Comment: Have you noted the fact that every prime  appearing in the factorization of $r$ ones, r prime bigger than three, is one more than a multiple of $r$? For example, $40,270$ are multiple of five. Similarly, $238,4648$ are multiples of seven. You may want to see why this is true

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг cool, i almost missed that observation.

Comment: To see why it is true, let $p > 3$ and $q$ be a prime factor of $\frac{10^p-1}{9}$. Then, $q \neq 2,3,5$(from their divisibility tests), so $q$ is a factor of $10^{q-1}-1$, and of $10^p-1$. That is, $10^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod q$ and $10^p \equiv 1 \mod q$. It is easy to see that if $x$ is the smallest positive integer with $10^x \equiv 1 \mod q$, then every $r$ satisfying $10^{r} \equiv 1 \mod q$ is a multiple of $x$. Since $q$ is not a factor of $10^1-1 = 9$, this forces $x = p$, since $r=p$ is possible. Now, $r=q-1$ is also possible, so $q-1$ is a  multiple of $p$.

Comment: In fact, $q-1$ is always a multiple of $2p$, since $q-1$ is also even.

Comment: It can easily be shown that $p$ must be a prime number, but there is no way to easily characterize the exponents for which $R_p$ (a common notation for $p$ ones) is prime. But upto a quite high limit , all numbers have been checked.